# Magento notice message issue

Tags: php, magento

I used below code in breadcrumb template to display the notice and messages

```
<div class="GlobalerrorBox">
    <div class="container ">
        <div class="message fL">
            <?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?>
        </div>
    <div class="fR"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It is working for voucher code messages and add to cart messages
but Newsletter error message not displayed in this template.

I need to display newsletter messages in same breadcrumb template